# Bootstrap form validation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to validate my form which integrate with bootstrap, for that i am using following link . I followed every steps in the link . The problem I am facing here is after a text box validated a valid image (right mark) is not displying . can any one please in this.

http://twitterbootstrap.org/bootstrap-form-validation/

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="name" class="control-label col-xs-4">Name :</label>
 <div class="col-xs-8">
<div class="col-lg-8">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="teacherName"      id="teacherName"  placeholder="Enter Name">
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and js i am using is,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/commenJs/datepick.js"></script>
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/bootstrap-form-validation/assets/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script> 

<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/bootstrap-form-validation/assets/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/commenJs/script.js"></script> 

<script>
    addEventListener('load', prettyPrint, false);
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('pre').addClass('prettyprint linenums');
        });
    </script>
```

and css is 
    @import url('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    @import url('assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css');
    /* New styles */

```
label.valid {
width: 24px;
height: 24px;
background: url(assets/img/valid.png) center center no-repeat;
display: inline-block;
text-indent: -9999px;
}
label.error {
font-weight: bold;
color: red;
padding: 2px 8px;
margin-top: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please edit your question and show the exact code you are using, or create a jsfiddle.

Comment: @simbabque: you have exactly 10k reputation :D